# mongodb - php - aggregate projection and match

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to match criteria (cl=1) and then aggregate all the results by month (I've tried year/month/date as well to no luck).

When I run the code below it seems like it works properly, the output shows the months etc, however none of the stats are being added.

The $du field in Mongo is a MongoDate object.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

See very bottom for a code snippet that is searched by date and returns a result.

```
        $result = $collection->aggregate(
            array(
                array('$match' => array(
                    'cl' => $app_id) # application id, int such as "2"
                ),
                array('$project' => array(
                    //'year' => array('$year' => '$du'),
                    'month' => array('$month' => '$du'),
                    //'week' => array('$week' => '$du'),
                )),

                array('$group' => 
                    array(
                        '_id' => array(
                            'month' => '$month',
                        ),
                        'i' => array('$sum' => '$vs.i'),
                        'r' => array('$sum' => '$vs.r'),
                        'u' => array('$sum' => '$vs.u'),
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    '$sort' => array(
                        '_id' => -1
                    )
                ),
                array(
                  '$limit' => 14
                )
            )
        );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [month] => 10
                        )

                    [i] => 0
                    [r] => 0
                    [u] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => Array
                        (
                            [month] => 9
                        )

                    [i] => 0
                    [r] => 0
                    [u] => 0
                )
        .......
```

> ## working - searching by date

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2012-10-01 00:00:00"));
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime("2013-10-15 00:00:00"));
$cursor = $collection->find(array("du" => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end)));
while ($cursor->hasNext()) {
    $document = $cursor->getNext();
    print_r($document);exit;
}

# RESPONSE
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 51acbfd33dd49497848a8e5b
        )

    [cl] => 1
    [du] => MongoDate Object
        (
            [sec] => 1370275795
            [usec] => 0
        )

    [vs] => Array
        (
            [i] => 11
            [u] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stats aren't there because you haven't chosen to project them.  Project gives you _id by default, but anything else you want must be specified.

You'll need something like this instead of your current $project:

```
array('$project' => array(
    'month' => array('$month' => '$du'),
    'vs' => 1
))
```